# Create Background Submit Form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two form code (getresponse webform code and a normal formcode ). I want to have a single visible OPTIN FORM for only purposed to input user email address and when the user submit the FORM it will submit the getresponse webform code to the background. I know it will do some jquery and ajax can you show me example codes how to do it?

NORMAL FORM:

```
    <!--VISIBLE FORM -->
<form method="post" action="#" target="frame_result">
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
    <br />
    <input id="blast" type="button" value="GET FREE QOUTE" name="submit" />
</form>
<!--VISIBLE FORM -->
```

I want to get the email address on the visible form to put on getresponse webform email fields on the background and submit it on the background. I really want your help guys. thanks on advance. sorry for bad English :)

GET RESPONSE WEB FORM CODE MUST BE INVISIBLE TO THE USER and run to the background:

```
<div id="WFItem505952" class="wf-formTpl">
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_contact_webform.html"
method="post">
        <div id="WFIcenter" class="wf-body">
            <ul class="wf-sortable" id="wf-sort-id">
                <li class="wf-email" rel="undefined" style="display:  block !important;">
                    <div class="wf-contbox">
                        <div class="wf-labelpos">
                            <label class="wf-label">Email:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wf-inputpos">
                            <input class="wf-input wf-req wf-valid__email" type="text" name="email"></input>
                        </div>
                        <em class="clearfix clearer"></em>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="wf-submit" rel="undefined" style="display:  block !important;">
                    <div class="wf-contbox">
                        <div class="wf-inputpos">
                            <input type="submit" class="wf-button" name="submit" value="Sign Up!"
                            style="display:  inline !important; width: 120px !important;"></input>
                        </div>
                        <em class="clearfix clearer"></em>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="webform_id" value="505952" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is this for validation?

Comment: for email marketing purposes. I want to have to submit the getresponse webform to the background w/ the email address that from the visible form code email address.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2U9dB/1)

The error is only because my form does not have a valid action & method yet :-) Replace that with your and you'll be fine. I'm just showing how to make your second form hidden and submit it via your first form. You can pass on the variables to the second form if you need to.

HTML:

```
    <form id="form1">
    <h5>Form 1</h5>
    <label for="username"><span>Username</span><input name="username" id="username" type="text" /></label><br/>
    <label for="email"><span>Email</span><input name="email" id="email" type="text" /></label><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form 1" />
  </form>
  <form id="form2">
    <h5>Form 2</h5>
      <input type="text" name="username1" id="username1" />
      <input type="text" name="email1" id="email1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form 2"/>
  </form>
```

CSS:

```
/* Hiding Form 2 */
#form2{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#form1').on('submit', function(){
        $('#username1').val($('#username').val());
        $('#email1').val($('#email').val());
        $('#form2').submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks :-) I am new to jquery is your script pass the variable on the form2?

Comment: great I want to know how to pass the code to the form 2 before it send to the background :)

Comment: updated the code. if you hide the css property, you'll see that the values are passed

Comment: thanks I just try it but there's minor error saying 

Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function,

can you troubleshoot it?